# Google App Engine computed property date return throws exception

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have an issue with Google App Engine (Python) decorator `@db.ComputedProperty`.

I have a model like :

```
class Employee(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    date_of_join = db.DateProperty()

    @db.ComputedProperty
    def date_of_employment(self):
        return self.date_of_join
```

When I try to insert values into the model, it is throwing an exception as:

```
BadValueError: Unsupported type for property date_of_employment: <type 'datetime.date'>
```

Can't computedProperty return/insert date values?

### Edit

I have found a solution. Appengine accepts datetime for computed property, not date object:

```
class Employee(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    date_of_join = db.DateProperty()

    @db.ComputedProperty
    def date_of_employment(self):
        return datetime.combine(self.date_of_join, datetime.min.time())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you hit a bug in GAE, which doesn't allow to use a datetime.date as ComputedProperty.

There's an issue report for this in [their issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8720), but in case you are curious, the relevant code is here:

- **google/appengine/api/datastore_types.py:ValidateProperty**: Because datetime.date is not in the _VALIDATE_PROPERTY_VALUES, _PROPERTY_TYPES nor _PACK_PROPERTY_VALUES dicts
- **google/appengine/api/datastore_types.py:ValidateProperty**: because there's no implemented way to "pack" a datetime.date into a datastore-friendly value (i.e. long), as there is for datetime.datetime (PackDatetime)
- If you were using ndb, in **google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py:GenericProperty:_db_set_value**: Because ComputedProperty inherits from it, and _db_set_value does not contemplate datetime.date

However, in the words of one of the team members (check issue report):

> In the case of datetime.date, when ndb reads the ComputedProperty from the Datastore, it reads an integer with a time meaning. However, it does not know if it should convert it to a datetime.date or to a datetime.datetime. When you use a DateProperty or a DatetimeProperty, ndb knows which time to convert to based on the type of your property.

BTW: I'd recommend moving to the new ndb module instead of sticking with db (however, this particular case won't work there, either)